# How to remove actions and armatures using python

Tags: python, armature

I have an automation script that imports an FBX and then it exports the FBX

I have a set of animations that I want to import and export but what I see is that each animation exported has the previous animations inside it as well.

The simple script is this one:

```
animation_directory = "a"
export_animation_directory = "b"
animations = os.listdir(animation_directory)
for i,anim in enumerate(animations[:2]):

bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx( filepath = os.path.join(animation_directory,anim))
bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath= os.path.join(export_animation_directory,anim))
objs = bpy.data.objects
for obj in objs:
    objs.remove(obj, do_unlink=True)
```

But I don't see a way to remove those residual items after import
is there a way to remove them or "reset the project" in some way?

[image: residues]

I saw here: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataArmatures.html
that there should be a remove option but I don't see one

[image: methods available for bpy.types.BlendDataArmatures]

and I'm on version 2.92

[image: version]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer I believe you're looking for.

```
action = bpy.data.actions["name_of_action_to_delete"]
bpy.data.actions.remove(action, do_unlink = True)
```

bpy.data.actions.remove() is a function that removes an action data block from your file. Similarly, bpy.data.objects.remove() can be used for objects, bpy.data.armatures.remove() can be used for armatures, etc.

When you call the function, pass in the action as an argument. You can get access to the action data-block via `bpy.data.actions["action_name_here"]`